# C++ no instance of overloaded function error in vector with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef struct _cor {
    int x;
    int y;
} COR;

int main() {
    int n;

    cin >> n;

    vector<unique_ptr<COR>> v;
    v.reserve(n);

    for (int i = 0, tmp1, tmp2; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> tmp1, tmp2;
        COR *temp = new COR{tmp1, tmp2};
        v.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

I want to make a vector with a given number from input

I've set `v` vector as type of `unique_ptr<COR>` so element of `v` should be a pointer.

So I tried `push_back` method to add new pointer of `COR` with `new` operator but keep seeing an error in `v.push_back(temp);` says

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Tp=std::unique_ptr<COR, std::default_delete<COR>>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<COR, std::default_delete<COR>>>]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (COR *) -- object type is: std::vector<std::unique_ptr<COR, std::default_delete<COR>>, std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<COR, std::default_delete<COR>>>>
```

Why am I seeing this error?

Comment: Avoid *typedef'ing* stucts in C++. It will create more problems than it cures.

Comment: should I just use `struct _cor` as type keyword?

Comment: Yes, that's all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transfer (move) a unique_ptr into the vector slot instead of pushing a raw pointer.

Instead of this:

```
    COR *temp = new COR{tmp1, tmp2};
    v.push_back(temp);
```

This:

```
    std::unique_ptr<COR> uptr = unique_ptr<COR>(new COR{ tmp1, tmp2 });
    v.push_back(std::move(uptr));
```

Or better yet, take advantage of the `emplace_back` for a small optimization.

```
    auto ptr = new COR{ tmp1, tmp2 };
    v.emplace_back(ptr);
```

Also, this line looks suspicious and generates a compiler warning about tmp2 not being initialized:

```
    cin >> tmp1, tmp2;
```

You probably meant:

```
    cin >> tmp1 >> tmp2;
```

Putting it all together and inlining the pointer creation with the emplace call

```
for (int i = 0, tmp1, tmp2; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> tmp1 >> tmp2;
    v.emplace_back(new COR{ tmp1, tmp2 });
}
```

Comment: still a long way to go.. thanks for kind explanations. also with a typo fixed